# Android how to call external app like java

Tags: android

I am wondering how can I call an external java program from android activity. Eg. The java program will emulate as server application then my android app from phone will call the server and parse the necessary information.

Any tips? Thanks alot

Comment: You would use REST web services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you need a "server"? You can use a Service as long running process and if you want you can also retrieve data from the internet.

Edit:
In the comments ShenG Sheng mentioned that he was talking about a real server application that is running on a pc and he want to access it by his android application. Certainly it is possible, but he has to decide which technology he wants.

- Websockets
- REST API

I would prefer REST because it's an easy way to create an API and access it by using simple HTTP methods like GET and POST. REST is available for several languages, so it should be no problem for you to use it. Afterwards you can create a service on your Android application that communicates with this REST API and redirects information to your activity.

Comment: hmm coz I am trying to emulate a client/server architecture. So the server will emulate some processing and pass back some info to my phone and my phone will talk to another program like java program through nfc

Comment: why are you not using a server running on your laptop and your application is talking to this server? But As I said, if you want that server on your phone, you can use a service and a backgroundthread.

Comment: sorry for creating a misunderstanding for you. I meant the server is on the computer most likely Java program, then I will have my android app I want to communicate with the server and pass some information between them. Wondering is it possible? I have done socket(client server) in java before, are there any way? Thanks

Comment: aaaah ok!
Certainly it is possible. The question is, which technology do you want. I prefer REST because it is a simple way to create a API. But please edit your question to clarify the situation.

Comment: ok. thanks a lot! and sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: please mark the right answer, to show someone who is reading your question, what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a secondary application which uses a `Service` to listen for incoming socket connections.  You'd have to write all of the server code yourself and have it live inside of this `Service`.  However, it cannot be an off the shelf Java app (e.g. .jar or .class) as this does not work on Android.  Android's Java code is compiled down to dex code which is run by either ART or Dalvik runtime.  You'd likely be better off spinning up a Google Cloud Endpoint or AWS instance to handle the web API call.